# Help! Normals rendering every edge in substance and marmoset!

Tags: edges, normals, baking

Teaching myself blender and am having a blast, but during test bakes im running into this issue that has me smashing my head against the key board. No matter how many times i smooth, sharpen, or average the normals my mesh keeps rendering all of its individual edges. I never really had an issued with this from maya, so i figure that this is just me not knowing blender well enough!

[image]

As you can see even when i sharpen them the normals get all wonky. Any ideas on whats going on?

[image]

heres the wireframe, ill throw the blend file up as well!

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1yesV5NHGlWuFPoP7x3heN9yvtvGRl5vm

Comment: It would help if you included a screenshot that included the wireframe mesh, though I'm going to guess you've got a case of n-gons.

Comment: This looks rather strange indeed. it could also be that your flat surface is not perfectly flat. We definitely need a wireframe and possibly a blend file.

Comment: Sounds good, ill throw the blend file and an screenshot up as well

Comment: Link to drive is up, also ive flattened the fins but the shading on the quads is sill messed up. reseting the normals so far has no effect. Do normals lock in blende?